# Conflicting HTTPD and HTTPD24 files when running yum update prevents update

Tags: centos6, yum, httpd

[Similar conflict issues](https://serverfault.com/questions/642458/yum-dependency-conflicts-already-installed-package)

The files that are experiencing conflict issues are almost all the same as the ones in the link above. However, I am not trying to install php56w...etc like the person who posted the question in the link, I am just trying to `yum update`.

**I want to know how to resolve the conflicts to complete my `yum update`.**

```
Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install      31 Package(s)
Upgrade     334 Package(s)

Total size: 282 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.d/README conflicts between attempted installs of httpd24-httpd-2.4.34-18.el6.x86_64 and httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64
  file /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/magic conflicts between attempted installs of httpd24-httpd-2.4.34-18.el6.x86_64 and httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64
  file /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/logs conflicts between attempted installs of httpd24-httpd-2.4.34-18.el6.x86_64 and httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64
  file /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules conflicts between attempted installs of httpd24-httpd-2.4.34-18.el6.x86_64 and httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64
  file /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/run conflicts between attempted installs of httpd24-httpd-2.4.34-18.el6.x86_64 and httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64

Error Summary
```

---

(Background):

Originally, `httpd` was installed and due to security reasons `httpd24` was installed at a later date. (I was not around during the time of the original installations).  Currently, I do not know the reason behind the conflicts.

`yum` was also being blocked before this happened by a broken repo. I tried using the argument `--disablerepo=<nameofrepo>` to fix this but for some reason, it didn't work and I directly disabled it in the repo by changing `enable=1` to `enable=0`.
It was recommended [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/856432/yum-update-fails-error-cannot-retrieve-repository-metadata-repomd-xml-for-r).

---

I wanted to learn more and found [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3999661) article but it is subscriber-read-only by RH.

Is the only way to go about fixing this deleting or replacing the files as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21246680/disable-yum-transaction-check-for-file-conflict)?

Albeit the first answer's first few lines state:

> Replacing files from another RPM package is bad idea in most cases and
> I strongly advise against what you're trying to do. That said, apply
> following at your own risk.

If possible, I want to resolve the conflicts rather than use a destructive method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I do have access to [that subscriber-only article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3999661), and the solution it gives is pretty non-obvious.

The problem described there is that at some point `/etc/httpd` was made a symbolic link to `/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd`. This causes the old httpd package, which stores its configuration in `/etc/httpd`, to instead try to overwrite the files created by the newer package.

To verify that this is your problem, see if `/etc/httpd` is a symbolic link:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls -ld /etc/httpd
```

The solution is simply to remove the symlink.

```
[root@localhost ~]# rm -f /etc/httpd
```

---

NB: Your system goes out of support in less than two months. You should be upgrading to a current distribution (e.g. CentOS 8) as soon as possible.